Spring security - permitting all does not work
I try to exclude /actuator endpoints from being authenticated.
I have the following configuration:
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(
            HttpSecurity http,
            JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider) throws Exception {

        return http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .httpBasic(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(
                        authz -> authz
                                .requestMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/api/**").hasRole("USER")
                                .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .addFilterAt(new JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter(jwtTokenProvider), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();
    }

However, calling /actuator/info requires authorization.
When I register WebSecurityCustomizer like this, it works.
@Bean
public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
    return (web) -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers("/actuator/**");
}

but I get the following warning message:
You are asking Spring Security to ignore Mvc [pattern='/actuator/**'].  
This is not recommended -- please use permitAll via HttpSecurity#authorizeHttpRequests instead.

my application.yml config:
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: info, health, prometheus

Output from debug:
2024-04-23T10:04:56.267+02:00  INFO 69256 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] Spring Security Debugger                 : 

************************************************************

Request received for GET '/actuator/info':

org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@13de2731

servletPath:/actuator/info
pathInfo:null
headers: 
host: localhost:8080
connection: keep-alive
cache-control: max-age=0
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="124", "Google Chrome";v="124", "Not-A.Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
sec-fetch-site: none
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-user: ?1
sec-fetch-dest: document
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,pl;q=0.8
cookie: Idea-9db45725=ebc97136-1c3f-4057-a7c2-e1254e0cf200; JSESSIONID=DCD0D8B5278250DF2A0329311A9D5103


Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextHolderFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  CorsFilter
  LogoutFilter
  JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  AuthorizationFilter
]


************************************************************



2024-04-23T10:04:56.268+02:00 ERROR 69256 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid token
    at com.my.JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:41) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]


How do I configure /actuator/** to be ignored in the recommended way?

why have you written JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter there is a reason to why spring security does not have this type of filter built in by default and there are several recommendations against handing out JWTs to browsers. Writing custom homemade security is dangerous. How do you plan on logging out user for instance?

@Toerktumlare, the code I write is a PoC; I know it should never be deployed on production. However, this is not related to my question :)

then it should not be included in the question if it isnt relevant and you dont waant ppl commenting on it. Also enable spring security DEBUG logs and edit your question to incclude the logs so we cacn see the actual erason spring security is denying your request

@Toerktumlare, I would argue that it gives more context, so I included it there. Also, I added debug output.

I recommend to set up two security filter chains for your application. One for the api and one for the actuators.
The first thing i noticed in your code is that you did not utilize the securityMatcher method and the second thing you have to know is that two security filter chains must be configured separately in two different beans.
I configured the actuators and a simple demo controller in my application. The controller listens to /api/demo and requires basic authentication. The actuators don't require authentication.
This is the (working, I just tested it) security configuration:
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain actuatorSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .securityMatcher("/actuator/**")
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().permitAll());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain apiSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .securityMatcher("/api/**")
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }
}


The problem was in the filter. All requests come through this filter, which should add authorization if needed.
So instead of:
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(@NonNull HttpServletRequest request, @NonNull HttpServletResponse response, @NonNull FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String token = resolveToken(request);
        if (token != null && validateToken(token)) {
            Authentication authentication = getAuthentication(token);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            doFilter(request, response, filterChain);
        }else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid token");
        }
    }

I refactored it to:
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(@NonNull HttpServletRequest request, @NonNull HttpServletResponse response, @NonNull FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String token = resolveToken(request);
        if (token != null && validateToken(token)) {
            Authentication authentication = getAuthentication(token);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            
        }

        doFilter(request, response, filterChain);
    }

Keep in mind that in production-ready projects you should use something like: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html
